# Dell Type C Dock WD15 has Blinking Monitor

Tags: firmware, docking-station, usb-c, flashing

Dell has a knowledge base article addressing this [blinking monitor](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln308209/dell-dock-wd15-troubleshooting-an-issue-with-the-external-monitors-blinking-between-video-and-no-video?lang=en) problem.  It is about updating drivers and flashing the firmware of the dock.  I have two problems with the instructions in that article.

- First, my Dell docking station is not attached to a Dell computer. 
  Dell's article assumes I am connected to a Dell computer.
- Second, when I call Dell technical support, they do not recognize either the "service tag" or "express service code" that are printed on the Dell dock!

In my case, I [purchased the Dock from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0M46KO) back in July of 2016 and I'm using it with a non-Dell laptop (a Lenovo Yoga running Windows 10 Pro).  It always had this blinking problem, but now it is worse.

Has anyone figured out if it is safe to flash the dock's firmware from a non-Dell machine?  Any other solutions known?

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a phone number to contact Dell.  I found a place titled "General Phone Numbers" and called the number for "Monitor Support" even though my question was not about a monitor.  All the other phone numbers sounded like paid support.

During a 2+ hour call, they:

- Confirmed that the "service tag" and "express service" code on the Dell dock were unknown to Dell, and this is due to a manufacturing problem they had in the past.
- They assigned to me a "dummy" service tag, ignoring what was printed on the dock.
- They asked and took control of my non-Dell laptop and attempted to flash the dock's firmware (no other initial steps were taken...they simply jumped to that step). The flash application failed to launch; it didn't even give an error message.  Perhaps it won't launch if it detects it is not on Dell hardware?  They didn't know.
- They concluded that they simply needed to send me a brand new dock.

I was told that as long as they had the WD15 (or better) dock in stock, it would arrive at my home in 24 to 48 hours.  They said nothing about me sending back the old one.  We'll see.

Aside from all this, I now know that Dell has no compunction about trying to flash the firmware of the Dock from a non-Dell laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have many of those with the same issue - the advice Dell gives about UEFI firmware and BIOS updates are useless.

The only way we have found to deal with it is to hold the power button in for 30 sec after removing all power, USB-C included, turn it on when power is inserted, and do it again. This will reset it for a while and your monitors should behave normally (sometimes up to 6 months).